# self.detailViewController.event.title == NULL is not working in iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, ekevent

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{   

    if (viewController == self && self.detailViewController.event.title == NULL)
    {

    }
}
```

`self.detailViewController.event.title == NULL` is working well in iOS 4.3, But not working in iOS 5.1.1

After deleting the event the title still has the value...

Anyone know the solution, pls suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the event object is being deallocated but it's title property still has a value then the event object is not being deallocated. Something must be retaining it, or it hasn't been auto released yet. Are you using ARC or manual retain/release?

Or do you mean the events title is being deleted in which case you want to do a string comparison?

Comparing something to nil or NULL is equivalent to comparing to 0, if it's a string compare you want to do then use NSString's isEqualToString method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved,

By checking again in the Calendar whether the event deleted or not.

This issue is also in SimpleEKDemo in apple's source code.

Anyway thanks for your help.